# Insufficient privileges to activate the "security defaults" option in "Azure Active Directory"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal, multi-factor-authentication

My company has created an Azure subscription and I am the Owner. In order to enable two-factor authentication for accessing the Azure portal, I would like to activate the `security defaults` option in `Azure Active Directory` > `Properties` > `Manage security defaults`.

However if I set `Yes` and save it says `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`.

How can I activate this option? Or is there a different way to enable two-factor authentication?

[image]

Comment: You said that you are the Owner of the Subscription, but are you a Global Administrator of your tenant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I assigned the **`owner`** role to the user like below:

[image]

When I tried to **`Manage security defaults`**, I got the same error as below:

[image]

Please **note** that, to **`Manage security defaults`**, you must sign-in as Global Administrator.

*To assign user the **Global Administrator** role,*

*Azure Active Directory -> Users -> Select User -> Assigned Roles -> Add assignments*

[image]

The **active assignments** will be reflected like below:

[image]

After assigning Global Administrator, I am able to update **`Manage security defaults`** successfully like below:

[image]